# How to configure Jetty in HTTP2 with external ssl offloading

Tags: jetty, http2, embedded-jetty

All examples under https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project have ssl factory in them.

In my case ssl offloading is done at nginx level with self signed cert.

What I need is just h2 connector (don't even h1) configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup Jetty with the `h2c` connector using the `HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory`.

If you are using `jetty-home` (or the older `jetty-distribution`), just enable the `http2c` module.

If you are using embedded-jetty, use the following rough outline for your connector.

```java
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
// ... configure 

HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory http2c = new HTTP2CServerConnectionFactory(config);
ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(this, http1, http2c);
connector.setPort(port);
server.addConnector(connector);
```